# iOS - When pic1 is touched by pic2, how do I make the game over?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewanimation

I am creating a game in single view. I want a game over screen when the animation for pic1 is touched by pic 2.

```
@IBOutlet weak var Pic1: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var Pic2: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var GameOver: UILebel!

self.Pic1.hidden = false
self.Pic1.center = CGPointMake(372.0, 45.0)
UIView.animateWithDuration(10.0, delay: 69.69, options: .Repeat, animations: {
    self.Pic1.center.y += 700
    }, completion: nil)

self.Pic2.hidden = false
self.Pic2.center = CGPointMake(207, 635)

func gameOver() {
    GameOver.hidden = false
    Pic1.hidden = true
    Pic2.hidden = true
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mentioned when an object touches an object, this is called collision detection, if you made a search on google like "swift iOS collision detection" then you will get decent results that explain how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You should use SpriteKit for this, makes it very easy.